# Why am I able to call a 32 bit COM library from an AnyCPU .NET web application running in IIS7 in 64 bit mode?

Tags: c#, asp.net, com, iis-7, 32bit-64bit

Without using a COM+ proxy service, I'm quite happily able to use classes from a 32 bit COM interop library from a .NET application compiled with target AnyCPU, running in a 64 bit w3wp process.

I'm successfully instantiating classes from a 32 bit COM interop library in a 64 bit .NET process.

w3wp is running in 64 bit mode, and the IIS configuration is set to not allow 32 bit applications. Ontop of that is the fact that there's a specifically x64 compiled and registered .NET assembly down the line.

I'm just wondering, how is this at all possible?

Of interest is that this works just beautifully if the code is compiled with Visual Studio 2008, targeting the 3.5 framework. If the same code is compiled with Visual Studio 2010, targeting the 3.5 framework, the application fails spectacularly when it tries to load the 32 bit COM interop library. As it should.

Comment: The w3wp process can run in 32-bit mode and thus can handle 32bit assemblies.

Comment: Which version of Visual Studio did you use to develop you .NET app?

Comment: I'm sorry, I thought that was obvious from the compiler choices - Visual Studio 2008 for the version that "works", Visual Studio 2010 for the version that doesn't.

Comment: As of VS 2010 it is no longer obvious, as this can target multiple frameworks.

Comment: Target, yes, but VS2010 always uses MSBuild4, as far as I'm aware?

Comment: Out of interest, is the COM library you're consuming an InProc or Out of Process library (as in it launches its own process ala Word, Excel interop)?

Comment: @Kev, It's a binary reference in the project, and classes instantiated right off. InProc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll chalk this up to some complexity in the tonnes of code and projects that the solution consists of. Removing the requirements of the offending library to be 64 bits has solved the issue, but naturally doesn't answer the question. It just makes it obsolete.

Answer (score 3):

It will be running in 32-bit mode if it is running at all, you cannot have 32bit stuff in a 64bit process and vice versa.  A process is entirely one or the other.

That is not the same as running a 32bit process on a 64bit host, obviously, that works.

The other alternative is that the third party stuff is actually providing a 64bit reference, and your conclusion of it running 32bit is incorrect.

Comment: w3wp.exe does not have the little 32 bit marker next to it in the Task Manager.

Comment: Also, explain to me why it fails when compiled with .NET4, and not when compiled with .NET2. =)

Comment: Well, that starts to depend on if you are embedding the interop types in the compiled DLL.  Also, it might be IIS running CLR 2 instead of 4?  Not sure about that part.

Comment: Now, there's the first good tip I've had in days. However, that will require me to change all the linked and referenced assemblies in my application to the 4.0 framework version, won't it?

Comment: Right. What I'm doing is, is compiling using Visual Studio 2010, targeting 3.5.

Comment: OK well that won't make a difference to what CLR the IIS process uses, but perhaps it doesn't have the relevant framework installed?  This is sounding like another question to be honest.

Comment: No, everything is installed right, I'm fairly certain. Both frameworks, and I can select 4.0 in the app pool framework dropdown.

Comment: To comment on your latest edit, I quite clearly get a "An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format." error when running with the VS2010 compiled code, and not the VS2008 compiled code.

Comment: Yeah, I know it's the bitness. That's the whole point of my question. =) No worries, I'm just stumped as to why it would work in one version of Visual Studio, but not another.

Answer (score 1):

You. Are. Not.

Point.

Put the web application to 32 bit mode. This is actually how they SHOULD run per MS IIS guidelines (that most people never bother to read).

Comment: No. You fail to see my actual question - I -am- able to. How is it possible?

Comment: @TomTom Can you put a link to that guideline that states to run web application pools in 32bit mode?

Comment: @Yiğit Yener: It is not a guideline that the application pool should be run in 32-bit mode. Rather it is a backward comaptibility feature that is documented. See: http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/201/32-bit-mode-worker-processes/

Comment: No, a guideliney. It makes rarels  yense to run worker processes IIS in sloer 64 bi mode - web apps should not get that large. Read the hosting guidelines. And no, 32 and 64 bit can not interoperate.

Answer (score 1):

The w3wp process can run in 32-bit mode and thus can handle 32bit assemblies. See whether your IIS service is running in 32-bit mode.

Comment: Again, not the issue. It runs just fine in 64 bit, without 32 bit enabled, when compiled with VS2008. But not when compiled with VS2010.

Answer (score 0):

It works through the DllSurrogate mechanism which automatically creates a DllHost process when you try to load a com-dll of the wrong bitness. In those cases you get implicit interprocess communication. Just take a look at main.